# Return the column index with the largest value for all rows (reverse one-hot encode)

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm basically looking for the equivalent on `np.argmax()` in Python. I have a data frame:

```r
> as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20, 0, 1), ncol=2))

           V1        V2
1  0.42718891 0.5263497
2  0.52157661 0.8216030
3  0.63448978 0.9766504
4  0.69304632 0.6446195
5  0.29205498 0.3424074
6  0.05661658 0.3009205
7  0.39710808 0.8118707
8  0.11667427 0.1558385
9  0.81182761 0.3003825
10 0.12070549 0.4928229
```

And I want a factor like this, with the column index where the largest value is for all rows:

```
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 [52] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 
[103] 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

I am aware that solutions have been posted on S/O. However, they are multiple lines and using multiple libraries and I'm looking for a solution where there aren't 20 different things that can go wrong.

Comment: Something like `apply(df, 1, which.max)`? (Or `apply(df, 1, which.max) - 1` to get zero-indexed)

Comment: That works. You can post it as an answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Comment: I would, but surely this is a duplicate. I'll look around for the appropriate link. EDIT: Nevermind, akrun came up with a way better answer anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
max.col(df1, 'first') - 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.42718891, 0.52157661, 0.63448978, 0.69304632, 
0.29205498, 0.05661658, 0.39710808, 0.11667427, 0.81182761, 0.12070549
), V2 = c(0.5263497, 0.821603, 0.9766504, 0.6446195, 0.3424074, 
0.3009205, 0.8118707, 0.1558385, 0.3003825, 0.4928229)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Whoa, I didn't even know about that function! Learn something new every day....